# NullPointerException while getting thread dump using jstack

Tags: java, jstack

I'm trying to debug a CPU spike issue. For fetching thread dump, I'm using Jstack which is giving below mentioned error:

```
Thread 1780: (state = IN_JAVA)
Error occurred during stack walking:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:78)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:60)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:221)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:136)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:102)
```

Has anyone seen this issue before ?

JDK version: 1.7

Comment: The StackTrace source (as reported by docjar) says that line 78 is trying to get the `externalNameAndSignature()` of the `java.lang.Method` of the topmost Java VM frame.  I suspect that the method is missing.  Perhaps you are not including a jar that was available when generating the thread dump?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8196969 seems to be the official bug report, but no workarounds.