# Not calling get on list of futures

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, executorservice

I'm using a global Executor service with some fixed thread pool size. We have bunch of related tasks that we submit for execution and wait on list of futures.

Recently, we faced a high CPU utilization issue and on debugging I found that an exception occurred while calling get() on one of the item in list of futures. Current, we iterate over the list and there is a try catch surrounding the whole loop.

```
try{
    List<Result> results = new ArrayList<>()
    for(Future<Result> futureResult: futureResults{
        Result result = futureResult.get();
        results.add(result);
    }
} catch(Exception e){
  throw new InternalServiceException(e);
}

//Do something with results
```

Wanted to know the behaviour of other threads if get is never called on some of the items in future. I tried searching but was not able to find anything.

Also, can this behaviour trigger high CPU utilization ?

Comment: Are you interested in the results?

Comment: I never run get on futures if the result isn't required. There is other pools without results if that's the case. But if the result is Interesting then i would check and put the ones not finished in a list for later lookup.

Comment: Why do you need to guess at what's causing your high CPU utilization? Why don't you run your code under a profiler and see exactly where the CPU is being used?

Comment: I tried using jstack and found that bunch of threads were in blocked state. Getting thread dump for thread with high CPU utilization triggered null pointer exception. Also, this issue is only reproducible in our production stack. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27865858/nullpointerexception-while-getting-thread-dump-using-jstack

Comment: Blocked threads are usually because of deadlocks when trying to use shared resources.

Comment: @yole Which CPU profiler is recommended at JetBrains ?

Comment: At JetBrains we use YourKit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.journaldev.com/1650/java-futuretask-example-program

I would still check if the future isDone as in the example above.

If you need to run other operations or want to utilize the CPU better then I would put the collector in a separate thread and perhaps just poll for results every minute or so.

Could be scheduled or handled by Thread.sleep.

Comment: I don't want to shutdown executor since it is a global executor. How will isDone() check help ? Also, I'm interested to find out behavior for other threads.Will this cause other threads to block ?

Comment: No it will not block other threads and a sleep will give the CPU back the time used by this thread.

Comment: The isDone helps because you'll not query the future for a result when a result isn't present.

Comment: Let's say, I have threads T1, T2 and T3 in list of future. I called get on T1 and an exception was thrown. So get was never called on T2 and T3. Lets say my global executor has 6 threads in total. After this process repeats 3 times what will happen if I submit more tasks to executor ?

Comment: All tasks will be qued and executed when a thread is free. And futures will be returned when done. If you done get the result the threads will still be free to handle new requests. But running get on a future that isn't done isn't advised.

Comment: In this case, future is done. But I never called get on it due to exception while calling get() in a for loop, does that mean those threads will remain blocked despite being in done state ? Or will they execute other tasks as soon as they are done. Where are the results stored once the thread is done but get is not called on it ?

Comment: The threads don't block even if you don't fetch the result. The future is just a container that could have a result or not. The thread executor will add the result to this container when the thread is done with it's execution.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped. This was the behavior I was seeing in my unit test as well

Answer (score 0):

Executors class provides various methods to execute Callable in a thread pool. Since callable tasks run in parallel, we have to wait for the returned Object.

Callable tasks return java.util.concurrent.Future object. Using Future we can find out the status of the Callable task and get the returned Object.

It provides get() method that can wait for the Callable to finish and then return the result.

There is an overloaded version of get() method where we can specify the time to wait for the result, it’s useful to avoid current thread getting blocked for longer time.

Future provides cancel() method to cancel the associated Callable task. There are isDone() and isCancelled() methods to find out the current status of associated Callable task.

Here is a simple example of Callable task that returns the name of thread executing the task after some random time. 
We are using Executor framework to execute 10 tasks in parallel and use Future to get the result of the submitted tasks.

```
public class FutureObjectTest implements Callable<String>{

    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        long waitTime = (long) (Math.random()*10000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " waiting time in MILISECONDS " + waitTime);
        Thread.sleep(waitTime);
        return Thread.currentThread().getName() + " exiting call method.";
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        List<Future<String>> futureObjectList = new ArrayList<Future<String>>();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Callable<String> futureObjectTest = new FutureObjectTest();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Future<String> futureResult = executorService.submit(futureObjectTest);
            futureObjectList.add(futureResult);
        }
        for(Future<String> futureObj : futureObjectList){
            try {
                System.out.println(futureObj.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Starting get method of wait");
        ////////////get(Timeout) method///////
        futureObjectList.clear();
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
            Future<String> futureResult = executorService.submit(futureObjectTest);
            futureObjectList.add(futureResult);
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        for(Future<String> futureObj : futureObjectList){
            try {
                System.out.println(futureObj.get(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```